# What are the steps i need to take while changing from http to https my Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, centos

I need to change my whole site working on https instead http.I have changed http part of WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) to https from Settings->General but the whole site is down. What steps i need to perform to convert wordpress site from http to https. I have CentOS release 6.3 (Final) installed.

Comment: Have you purchased SSL certification for your server ?

Comment: Can i buy this later? i just want to test that my site is able to work on https or not.

Comment: you can get a cert for free with Letsencrypt or you can generate a self signed cert but the letsencrypt is just as easy and will not give you errors

Answer (score 3):

To make a website HTTPS, firstly get an SSL certificate for the domain, install it on the server and change the website permalinks from http to https.

Admin Setting:

1. Go to the admin dashboard.
2. Point you mouse over Settings and click General.
3. Where it says WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) replace the `http://` part with `https://` for both of them.
4. Click Save Changes

To easily enable (and enforce) WordPress administration over SSL, the constant `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` should be set to true in your site's `wp-config.php` file to force all logins and all admin sessions to happen over SSL.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

To setup a 301 permanent redirect, FTP/SFTP to your server and add the code below at the top of WordPress' `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Change every instance of yoursite.com to your WordPress URL.

To inform Google about the change in URL, re-add your WordPress site to Google webmaster tool (but this time with `https://`).

Hope it will help.

Comment: Do i need to install mod_ssl on my server?

Comment: yes, you will need mod_ssl installed, you can use wp-cli to change all instances of http to https as well to alleviate any future warnings

Answer (score 1):

What Techie Code said is correct...

Also Don't mention HTTP or HTTPS in your image path. Just keep it like  `//yoursite.com/img/image.jpg`  so it will keep track of http or https automatically. This is called as `Protocol Relative URL`'s.

Check here The Protocol-relative URL `http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/`